# Jest testing Node JS file error from Mock FS

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, fs

I have followed the basic examples, and using an asynchronous read of a file, I cannot test the failure of the file read. Using Mock-FS to do the testing, the success cases all pass, but the failure generates an unhandled exception error.

ReadFileContents.ts

```
import * as NodeJSFS from 'fs';

export async function ReadFileContents(Directory:string, FileName:string):Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        NodeJSFS.readFile(
            `${Directory}/${FileName}`,
            (error: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null, FileContents: Buffer) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(FileContents.toString());
                }
            },
        );
    });
}
```

ReadFileContents.spec.ts

```
import * as MockFS from 'mock-fs';
import { ReadFileContents } from './read-file-contents';

describe('ReadFileContents', () => {
    afterAll( async () => {
        MockFS.restore();
    });
    afterEach( async () => {
        MockFS.restore();
    });
    beforeEach( async () => {
        MockFS( {
            'datafiles': {
                'abc.txt': '{ "FirstLine": "This is the first line", "LastLine": "This is the last line" }',
                'abc.hdr': 'Server|MyServer',
            }
        }, {
            // add this option otherwise node-glob returns an empty string!
            createCwd: false
        } );
    });

    it('should have the proper files in the mocked data', () => {
        expect(MockFS.length).toBe(2);
    });

    it('should load the proper file data abc.txt', async () => {
        ReadFileContents('./datafiles', 'abc.txt').then( FileContent => {
            expect(FileContent).toContain('This is the first line');
        });
    });

    it('should load the proper file data from abc.hdr', async () => {
        ReadFileContents('./datafiles', 'abc.hdr').then( FileContent => {
            expect(FileContent).toContain('Server');
        });
    });

    // it('should return an exception when the file does not exist', async () => {
    //  expect(async () => await ReadFileContents('./datafiles', 'FileDoesNotExist.Missing')).not.toThrow();
    // });
});
```

Also, this test will have the same error:

```
it('should return an exception when the file does not exist', async () => {
    await expect(ReadFileContents('./datafiles', 'FileDoesNotExist.Missing'))
        .rejects
        .toThrow();
});
```

The error handling above, for a missing file, generates the following error:

```
node:internal/process/promises:245
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Error: EBADF, bad file descriptor".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
```

Without the error condition tests, I do get the following warning error for the unit tests, even though the tests pass.

```
node:internal/process/promises:245
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[Error: EAGAIN: resource temporarily unavailable, read] {
  errno: -11,
  code: 'EAGAIN',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Comment: I resolved this with the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68197740/755666.  I changed the code to use the fs/promises version of readFile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this with the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68197740/755666.  I changed the code to use the fs/promises version of readFile.

I changed the code to be:

```
import * as NodeJSFSPromises from 'fs/promises';
import * as NodeJSPath from 'path';

export async function ReadFileContents(Directory:string, FileName:string):Promise<string> {
    const PathAndFileName = NodeJSPath.format( { dir: Directory, base: FileName });
    const FileContents$:Promise<Buffer> = NodeJSFSPromises.readFile(PathAndFileName);
    const Contents:string = (await FileContents$).toString();
    return Contents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In catch block, you are rejecting error. Error should be of type string as you expect promise to return string.

Comment: This does not correct the unhandled exception error.  The promise is to return a string when successful, but the reject() with a string still has the same unhandled exceptions.